# Strange firefox bug

Tags: firefox, debug

whenever i type any address and click go, it gives some strange error.

for example , when i type "www.google.com" it freezes for sometime and gives me error as follow:

> File Not Found
>
> Firefox can't find the file at jar:file:///C:/Program Files/Mozilla Firefox/chrome/en-US.jar!/locale/browser-region/region.propertieswww.google.com
>
> - Could the item have been renamed, removed, or relocated?
> - Is there a spelling, capitalization, or other typographical error in the address?
> - Do you have sufficient access permissions to the requested item?

so can't open any site in firefox , can anyone tell me whats the problem

this problem has been observed by all the firefox versions installed in my pc i.e. 3.0.11, 3.5 and 3.5.1

edited after 1st 2 answers:

there is one more problem of freezing.
whenever i click on any link or click any button in browser it freezes for atleast 15 seconds.

Comment: After removing ask toolbar and disabling all add-ons i can now open sites in browser but "15 sec freezing after every click in the browser" seems to frustrate me.

Comment: Nice question title "strage firefox bug" - very detailed, probably this is why I would prefer to do house-laundry than doing technical support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the interesting part of this error is that he's typing in a web address and Firefox is prepending

`file:///C:/Program Files/Mozilla Firefox/chrome/en-US.jar!/locale/browser-region/region.properties`

to the address.  If the above solutions don't fix the issue I would completely remove FF, delete the folder under Program Files to be sure and reinstall.

Comment: thnx it worked.

Answer (score 3):

Try disabling all of your add-ons.  (Like the Ask toolbar.)  Then restart the browser and see if the problem still exists.  I've noticed sometimes that firefox won't load a web page for me, but when I disable the StumbleUpon toolbar, it works just fine.

Comment: or, run firefox in "safe mode" which disables all addons..

Answer (score 2):

This [thread](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=934345) suggests the problem might be with Ask.com toolbar add-on which apparently can come when you install the COMODO firewall

Answer (score 2):

Do you have the Ask toolbar installed?
If so, retry [after removing it](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Uninstalling_toolbars).

> In some cases, you may also need to [reset preference settings](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Resetting_preferences) related to the toolbar after disabling or uninstalling it.
>
> In particular, toolbars that include an Internet search feature (such as the [Ask.com Toolbar](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Problematic_extensions#Ask.com_Toolbar)) change the default search provider by modifying the Keyword.URL preference.

Comment: removed ask toolbar.........but the freezing problem still persists...

Answer (score 2):

I get a similar problem when using certain proxies. It freezes and will sometimes come up after a short-ish wait. Then pages seem to load a lot quicker.

I would try resetting Firefox to its default configuration (i.e. no proxies, no extensions, security at default levels). I realize though that you've tried this with several versions. Maybe each time you're importing the proxy settings from IE?

Maybe something has changed on the proxy end of things?

Comment: yes i have been using proxies over long period of time but firefox has started behaving this way recently. but i agree that proxy has something to do in this matter