# Ask.com removes other search engines from Firefox?

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, browser-addons, toolbar

Ask.com just deleted all search engines from my Firefox. Needless to say, I have never used it - probably some Add-on changed these defaults. I am using Ubuntu 8.04.

I would like all my original search engines back, but pressing "Restore defaults" just brings up Ask.com again; I'm looking for the file where these settings are stored.

**How can I restore the default search engines that are supplied with Firefox? What file are they stored in?**

By the way, this is a  very ugly practice - removing all search engines but yourself? I will never touch their website with a stick

Thanks,
Udi

Comment: Do you have Comodo?

Comment: I think you should remove the google tag since it's only tangentially related to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i am not sure whether ask.com toolbar affects any other search engines or not but i can certainly tell you that there are many other possible side effects of that toolbar. 
you can take look at [strange firefox bug](https://superuser.com/questions/24136/strange-firefox-bug)

i would recommend reinstalling firefox without keeping any preferences for next install.

Answer (score 3):

Try this tip from the [mozilla community documentation pages](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Search_Bar):

> **Restoring default search engines**
>
> Default search engines that come
>   pre-installed in Firefox currently
>   include Google, Yahoo, Amazon.com,
>   Answers.com, Creative Commons, eBay,
>   and in Firefox 3, Wikipedia. If you
>   have removed any of the default search
>   engines. you can restore them using
>   the "Manage Search Engines "Restore
>   Defaults" button. This will not remove
>   any added search engines. (If the
>   "Restore Defaults" button is disabled
>   or "grayed-out", as shown above, that
>   means that all of the default search
>   engines are still available).
>
> **Another way you can restore the
>   default set of search engines is to
>   use the Firefox Safe Mode option,
>   *Restore default search engines*. This
>   will add back all of the default
>   search engines if some of them are
>   missing.** This will not remove any
>   added search engines.

You can invoke firefox in safe-mode from the command line:

> firefox -safe-mode

Comment: Didn't work. They must have deleted some configuration file, which is really nasty.

Comment: Agree. I'd just reinstall if I were you. Lately there has been a spurt in the number of misbehaving, borderline malicious Firefox addons. It hasn't come at a good time for the Firefox team.