# Did eBay remove itself from the list of Firefox search engines?

Tags: firefox, search, search-engines

Firefox 49.0.1

Windows 7 Pro 64bit SP1

I no longer see eBay as a search engine in Firefox and can't seem to add it in or restore it back.  It's also missing from another Firefox based browser bundle.

- I've done a quick search on the net and found nothing relevant.
- I've tried manually adding it
- I've tried [restoring it](https://superuser.com/questions/24167/ask-com-removes-other-search-engines-from-firefox/24900#24900), but the button is greyed out
- I've tried adding it via the linked extension/search search provided in the search engine GUI (there wasn't what looked like a default eBay search, but a lot of specific extensions).
- I tried removing Bing and Yahoo and then restoring the engines.  Those two come back, but eBay does not.  My default goes back to Yahoo too :-/
- I tried going to eBay, and the plus button on the magnifier does not show up.
- The plus button on the magnifier shows up on this site, so that's working.

Did eBay remove itself from the list of Firefox search engines?

Comment: I noticed this a week or two ago as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can find it at addons.mozilla.org as 'eBay Search Suggestions". Why it was removed from the built-in list, God only knows.

[Direct link to page](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/ebay-search-suggestions-259370/?src=ss)

Comment: I've no specific knowledge here, but probably lack of willingness to pay Mozilla - Mozilla tend to charge for things like that.

Comment: @davidgo I'm not aware of Mozilla charging anyone for hosting their FF add-ons.
BTW OP the link doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Add a search engine

Many websites offer search engines that you can add to your Firefox Search bar. This allows you to search that specific website directly from your Search bar.

1. To add the site-specific engine, visit the website for your desired search engine. (We'll use youtube.com as an example.)
2. Click the magnifying glass on the Search bar on your toolbar, then click Add "YouTube Video Search".

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/add-or-remove-search-engine-firefox

Comment: That doesn't work, and I explained that in the OP.

Answer (score 0):

I have been wondering about this myself, it appears that Ebay revoked Mozilla's permission* to use their logo in the browser which resulted in a change to remove the search plugin ([1](http://techdows.com/2016/09/firefox-50-ebay-search-engine-removed.html), [2](https://www.reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/5559sk/ebay_search_gone_from_list_of_oneclick_search/)). So it's no an issue on your end. The corresponding ticket on Bugzilla appears to be not open to the public according to a german [developer and blogger](http://stadt-bremerhaven.de/firefox-50-veroeffentlicht-bringt-neue-tastaturkuerzel-und-mehr/#comment-758155).

*On second though: I don't know about the financial details, but perhaps Mozilla wanted to negotiate the terms to include Ebay by default and that didn't go so well. May be there are details about this in their [annual reports](https://blog.mozilla.org/blog/2016/12/01/state-of-mozilla-2015-annual-report/), but it's not so important to me to invest more time into this at the moment.